# How to use set @ variable in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I want set a select list as variable and do some conditional check on it:

This is my code which is not working:

```
set @temp = (select docId from table_1);
SELECT 
   id,
   CASE when id IN (@temp) then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end as visited
FROM table_2;
```

Also tried this:

```
set @temp = (select docId from table_1);
SELECT 
   id,
   CASE when (FIND_IN_SET(id,@temp)=1) then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end as visited
FROM table_2;
```

In both case, visited column is coming FALSE for each row.

Comment: Why not simply do: `select docId from table_1`

Comment: My actual code is different. I am using this feature to do some task. Have not written all the things over here. My main problem is coming in this task. The picture is very unclear that what happens exactly when i do set @variable.

Comment: You need to give more details, otherwise question seems very trivial atm.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Check now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` with `GROUP BY` instead. Left joining may result in duplicate rows corresponding to table_2 (as there can be multiple rows for same `id` value in the table_1); to handle that, we will use `Group By`. `Count()` function can be used to determine if `id` exists in the table_1 or not, and accordingly determine TRUE/FALSE.

Try the following:

```
SELECT 
   t2.id,
   CASE WHEN t1.docId IS NOT NULL THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS visited
FROM table_2 t2
LEFT JOIN table_1 t1 ON t1.docId = t2.id
```

Comment: CASE WHEN t1.docId is not null THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS visited..... is precisely working for me.

Comment: This count is merging all the rows into one , which is incorrect.

Comment: @lil-wolf it will group by on `id` so you will get one row per `id`. This is what your earlier query is also supposed to achieve. Unless your actual requirement is different.

Comment: But this count is giving me one row per 'whole table'. First comment is working for me. Left join will not duplicate the ids. anyway i am getting one row per id by left joining itself.